# TypeError Too many Arguments

Tags: python, syntax-error, line

When running this code it appears with an error that there are too many arguments in line 8. I'm unsure on how to fix it.

```
#Defining a function to raise the first to the power of the second.
def power_value(x,y):
    return x**y

##Testing 'power_value' function
#Getting the users inputs
x = int(input("What is the first number?\n"))
y = int(input("What power would you like to raise",x,"to?\n"))

#Printing the result
print (x,"to the power of",y,"is:",power_value(x,y))
```

Resulting in a TypeError...

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\[bla location]", line 8, in <module>
    y = int(input("What power would you like to raise",x,"to?\n"))
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the python input() function was only ready to accept one parameter - the prompt string, but you passed in three. To solve this issue, you just need to combine all three pieces into one.

You can use the `%` operator to format string:

```
y = int(input("What power would you like to raise %d to?\n" %x,))
```

Or use the new way:

```
y = int(input("What power would you like to raise {0} to?\n".format(x)))
```

You can find the document [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Thanks, it just I'm not to sure on how the '%' operator works

Answer (score 2):

Change your `y` input line to

```
y = int(input("What power would you like to raise" + str(x) + "to?\n"))
```

So you will concatenate the three substrings into a single string.

Comment: Yes I have used comas to separate them when it should be like that. Thanks :D

Comment: No, it shouldn't be like that. Use `format` as others suggested.

Comment: @Matthias "it shouldn't"? Why is that? It works fine.

Comment: It works, but it lacks flexibility. With `format` you can control the result much better. Additionally: In your example you're missing the blanks around the number. Using a format-string you would see it at once.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify `x` variable :

using [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
y = int(input("What power would you like to raise {}to?\n".format(x)))
```

or

```
y = int(input("What power would you like to raise %d to?\n"%x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` accepts **one** argument which it prints to the screen. You can read about `input()` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
In your case you are providing 3 arguments to it ->

1. The String `"What power would you like to raise"`
2. The integer `x`
3. The String `"to?\n"`

You can combine these three things together like this and form one argument

```
y = int(input("What power would you like to raise"+str(x)+"to?\n"))
```

Comment: Please provide more context to the answer. Moreover, i still see syntax errors in the answer.